# html5 canvas mirroring objects

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote the following code in my text editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
    <head>
        <script>

        window.onload = function()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasArea");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var ball = new Image();
            var smallImage = "https://i.warosu.org/data/sci/img/0076/83/1448614341262.png";

            var ballXPos = 75;
            var ballYPos = 15;
            var ballWidth = 90;
            var ballHeight = 90;

            var reflectAdj = 3.5;
            var reflectAlpha = .4;
            var reflect Y = (2*ballYPos) + (2*(ballHeight-reflectAdj));

            var gradLV = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);

            ball.onload = function()
            {
                gradLV.addColorStop( 0, "lightskyblue");
                gradLV.addColorStop(.3, "orange");
                gradLV.addColorStop(1, "blue");

                context.fillStyle = gradLV;
                context.fillRect(0, 0, canvs.width, canvas.height);

                context.translate(0, reflectY);

                context.scale(1,-1);

                context.globalAlpha = reflectAlpha;

                context.drawImage(ball, ballXpos, ballYpos, ballWidth, ballHeight);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style = "width:400px;  height:210px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
            <canvas id = "canvasArea" width = "400" height = "210"
            style = "border:2px solid black">
                Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this code, the canvas is supposed to show a mirrored object, but the canvas is completely blank. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong/ PLease and thank you.

Comment: First please try to fix so many errors, try to debug with console.log or it even triggers ball.onload. var reflect Y -> fatal error.  context.drawImage(ball, ballXpos, ballYpos, ballWidth, ballHeight -> some variables even does not exist! Typos, so many typos. You are trying to code totally blind..

Answer (score 0):

Your code was full of a number of small errors, most of which were typos. You were also failing to specify the image URL as the `src` of the `new Image()` constructor.

The code below fixes these issues and provides visual output on the canvas. I'm not sure exactly what mirror effect you're going for, but hopefully this sets you on the right path.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasArea");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var ball = new Image();
  ball.src = "https://i.warosu.org/data/sci/img/0076/83/1448614341262.png";

  var ballXPos = 75;
  var ballYPos = 15;
  var ballWidth = 90;
  var ballHeight = 90;

  var reflectAdj = 3.5;
  var reflectAlpha = .4;
  var reflectY = (2*ballYPos) + (2*(ballHeight-reflectAdj));

  var gradLV = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);

  ball.onload = function() {
    gradLV.addColorStop( 0, "lightskyblue");
    gradLV.addColorStop(.3, "orange");
    gradLV.addColorStop(1, "blue");

    context.fillStyle = gradLV;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.translate(0, reflectY);

    context.scale(1,-1);

    context.globalAlpha = reflectAlpha;

    context.drawImage(ball, ballXPos, ballYPos, ballWidth, ballHeight);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style = "width:400px;  height:210px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
  <canvas id = "canvasArea" width = "400" height = "210" style = "border:2px solid black">
    Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
  </canvas>
</div>
```